# Add a line break into the long string in <li> React

Tags: reactjs

I have a string that shows some values separated by commas (,). when I added it to my < li > tag it shows perfectly if the values are less than 6 items. But if it exceeded I want it to move into the next line. Please find the screenshots

[image: Exceeded items]
[image: 6 items looks fine]

*following is my code*

```
<li>{movieData.seats}
<br/>( {seatCount.length} Tickets ) ODC <span>Rs . {(parseFloat(CalAdultPrice).toFixed(2))}</span>
</li>
```

any solutions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `{movieData.seats}` with some element and apply this styles to it:

```
word-break: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using JavaScript

You'll need to split your `movieData.seats` into an array of arrays. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) has various implementations of how to do it. My first thought was if you already are using lodash, you can use `_.chunk` to save yourself having to write your own.

Here's a quick example of making the 2d array:

```
const seats = 'A6,C5,B6,B5,B3,B2,B4,B2'
const splitSeats = seats.split(',')

const lineLength = 6

const chunk = (arr, length) => {
    let tmp = []

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += length) {
        tmp.push(arr.slice(i, i + length));
    }
    
    return tmp
}

console.log(chunk(splitSeats, lineLength))
```

Then to use it in your render:

```
// bla...
{chunkedArray.map(seats => (
    <React.Fragment key={/*some key here*/}>
        {seats.map(seat => <span key={seat}>{seat},</span>)}
        <br />
    </React.Fragment>
))}
// bla...
```

### Using HTML/ CSS

Wrap your `movieData.seats` in an element with a fixed width and use CSS to break up the string. e.g.

```
.seats {
    width: 140px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```